# Angular Material: Theming standard controls

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material2

I created my custom light theme for my website (which is quite close to indigo-pink). However, for some of the controls I would like to use a completely different look: let's say for drop down standard look is white with grey highlight, I would like a white with blue highlight. I found a way of overriding through the css but I am wonder if I can do it through my main SCSS file using mixins like for custom controls.

Answer (score 1):

Just import the theme separately into the specific mixin like what the mixin `angular-material-theme` does (which basically includes the theme to all the themes for specific components):

```scss
@include mat-button-theme($my-theme);
@include mat-card-theme($my-other-theme);
```

*Excerpt from `_all-palette.scss`*:

```scss
@mixin angular-material-theme($theme) {
    @include mat-core-theme($theme);
    @include mat-autocomplete-theme($theme);
    @include mat-button-theme($theme);
    @include mat-button-toggle-theme($theme);
    @include mat-card-theme($theme);
    @include mat-checkbox-theme($theme);
    @include mat-chips-theme($theme);
    @include mat-table-theme($theme);
    @include mat-datepicker-theme($theme);
    @include mat-dialog-theme($theme);
    @include mat-expansion-panel-theme($theme);
    @include mat-form-field-theme($theme);
    @include mat-grid-list-theme($theme);
    @include mat-icon-theme($theme);
    @include mat-input-theme($theme);
    @include mat-list-theme($theme);
    @include mat-menu-theme($theme);
    @include mat-paginator-theme($theme);
    @include mat-progress-bar-theme($theme);
    @include mat-progress-spinner-theme($theme);
    @include mat-radio-theme($theme);
    @include mat-select-theme($theme);
    @include mat-sidenav-theme($theme);
    @include mat-slide-toggle-theme($theme);
    @include mat-slider-theme($theme);
    @include mat-stepper-theme($theme);
    @include mat-tabs-theme($theme);
    @include mat-toolbar-theme($theme);
    @include mat-tooltip-theme($theme);
    @include mat-snack-bar-theme($theme);
```

}

- [More info](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#theming-only-certain-components)
- [`_all-palette.scss` (where the mixin `angular-material-theme` source code is)](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/theming/_all-theme.scss)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow Angular Material way, you can define multiple themes (color palletes) in your SCSS file and use them through `color="primary"` attribute, or `color="yourCustomPallete"`.

Comment: The `color` attribute only accepts three values: `primary`, `accent` and `warn`.